# if Font.Color is not black then delete cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue that I cannot understand, this is the script:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

   Dim WS_Count As Integer
   Dim I As Integer
   Dim ws As String
   Dim sht As Worksheet

   ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
   ' workbook.
   WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
   ws = ActiveSheet.Name

   ' Begin the loop.
   For I = 1 To WS_Count

        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws = Worksheets(I).Name
            Dim x As Range
            Set x = Worksheets(I).UsedRange
            x.ClearComments

            x.Replace What:="*€£$*", Replacement:=""

            For Each Cell In Worksheets(I).UsedRange
                If x.Font.Color <> Black Then
                    x.Delete
                End If
            Next
        Next sht

   Next I

End Sub
```

All of the code works with exception to:

```
For Each Cell In Worksheets(I).UsedRange
    If x.Font.Color <> Black Then
          x.Delete
    End If
Next
```

I've tried changing this to equaling black, this still doesn't work. I've tried stepping through at that point, it never finds a cell that would qualify to delete the cell.

Comment: I'd guess the font isn't actually black then. Have you tried selecting one of the cells and then testing `Activecell.font.color`?

Comment: The main thing I'm trying to achieve is delete all cells that do NOT contain the font colour black. There are definitely cells which are not black, but I will try the activecell idea to see if that works, thanks

Comment: Note, that any cell can (potentially) contain multiple colors. The first character in any given cell could be black while the second character could be red  and the third character could be green. So, you might want to check the first character in any given cell only like so: `If x.Characters(1,1).Font.Color <> vbBlack And x.Characters(1,1).Font.Color <> 5920858 Then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to `Cell` within your loop.  Like this:

```
For Each Cell In Worksheets(I).UsedRange
    If Cell.Font.Color <> vbBlack Then
          Cell.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was missing, I knew it would be something simple

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to colors directly in VBA. Instead, you need to work with their numeric reference. Since black is 0, your code ought to look something like this

```
For Each x In Worksheets(I).UsedRange
    If x.Font.Color = 0 Then
          x.Delete
    End If
Next
```

I've also changed For Each Cell to x because that's the variable you've defined in your code. And in this instance you want to test if the cell is equal to black, rather than not equal to

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually want to delete all cells where the font colour is not black hence the use of "<>". Unfortunately this still doesn't work, I've also tried x.Font.ColorIndex as that should be used when using the colour index, I thought?

Comment: You need to amend the title of your question

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed not!

Answer (score 0):

In your loop `For Each Cell In Worksheets(I).UsedRange`, you are looping through the Range with `Cell` (`Range` object), and afterwards you are checking if `If x.Font.Color <> Black Then` instead of `If Cell.Font.Color <> Black Then`.

Also, the `Cell.Font.Color` returns a numeric value, it should comapre against `vbBlack` and not `Black`.

**Modified Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim WS_Count As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim ws As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim x As Range ' define outside the loop
Dim C As Range

' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

' Begin the loop.
For I = 1 To WS_Count
    With Worksheets(I)
    'For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ' <-- No need for this loop
        ws = .Name

        Set x = .UsedRange
        x.ClearComments

        x.Replace What:="*€£$*", Replacement:=""

        For Each C In x ' I replaced Cell with C (Cell is too close to Cells)
            If C.Font.Color <> vbBlack Then
                C.Delete
            End If
        Next C
'        Next sht
    End With

Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Cell.Delete, beacuse you will recognize, your VBA will copy a cell instead of a not black cell.
This is a delete and copy.
You have to use, Cell.ClearContents.
And it will be delete, the cell contents!